# How to use the ELSIF statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

I'm wondering if I can run the if statement by itself, or it can't stand on its own, has to be in a nested statement. I can't directly run the following code.

```
IF tax_year=2005 THEN
UPDATE table1 SET column1=column1*3;
ELSIF tax_year=2006 THEN
UPDATE table1 SET column1=column1*5;
ELSIF tax_year=2007 THEN
UPDATE table1 SET column1=column1*7;
END IF;
```

Also, I didn't write it out that when tax_year=2008, column1=column1. I'm not sure if it needs to be in the code since column1 won't change in 2008.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with the following code:

```
-- UPDATE houston_real_acct_1single1property
-- SET convert_market_value=
-- CASE  
--         WHEN tax_year=2005 THEN total_market_value*1.21320615034169
--         WHEN tax_year=2006 THEN total_market_value*1.17961794019934
--         WHEN tax_year=2007 THEN total_market_value*1.15884093604151
--         WHEN tax_year=2008 THEN total_market_value*1.12145267335906
--         WHEN tax_year=2009 THEN total_market_value*1.11834431349904
--         WHEN tax_year=2010 THEN total_market_value*1.0971664297633
--         WHEN tax_year=2011 THEN total_market_value*1.06256515125065
--         WHEN tax_year=2012 THEN total_market_value*1.04321957955664
--         WHEN tax_year=2013 THEN total_market_value*1.02632796014915
--         WHEN tax_year=2014 THEN total_market_value*0.998472101797389
--         WHEN tax_year=2015 THEN total_market_value
-- END;
```

Answer (score 5):

`IF / ELSIF / ELSE` is part of `PL/pgsql`, which is an extension of pg, and it's enabled for new database by default.

You can create a function to wrap the `IF` statements. And call the function to execute these statements.

e.g

```
-- create function,
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_dummy_tmp(id_start integer, id_end integer) RETURNS setof dummy AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF id_start <= 0 THEN
        id_start = 1;
    END IF;

    IF id_end < id_start THEN
        id_end = id_start;
    END IF;

    return query execute 'select * from dummy where id between $1 and $2' using id_start,id_end;

    return;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- call function,
select * from fun_dummy_tmp(1, 4);

-- drop function,
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fun_dummy_tmp(integer, integer);
```

And, there is a `CASE` statement, which might be a better choice for your requirement.

e.g

```
-- create function,
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_dummy_tmp(id integer) RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE
    msg varchar;
BEGIN
    CASE id%2
        WHEN 0 THEN
            msg := 'even';

        WHEN 1 THEN
            msg := 'odd';
        ELSE
            msg := 'impossible';
    END CASE;

    return msg;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- call function,
select * from fun_dummy_tmp(6);

-- drop function,
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fun_dummy_tmp(integer);
```

You can refer to [postgresql document for control statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) for the details.